# How do I fix a segmentation fault with a pointer being passed from a function in C?

Tags: c, string, pointers, segmentation-fault

GDB is telling me that line 52 is causing a segmentation fault. I don't understand why. I am implementing a simple stack. It has two functions: pop and push. It appears pop is not working. The purpose of pop is to retrieve the top most value on the stack. However, when it attempts to do this I get a segmentation fault. Does anyone know the reason?

```
/*************************************************************************
 * stack.c
 *
 * Implements a simple stack structure for char* s.
 ************************************************************************/

// for strdup() in the testing code
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 500

#include <assert.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

// the capacity of the stack
#define CAPACITY 10

//global variable used to keep track of pop and push


typedef struct
{
    // storage for the elements in the stack
    char* strings[CAPACITY];

    // the number of elements currently in the stack
    int size;
}stack;

// declare a stack (as a global variable)
stack s;


/**
 * Puts a new element into the stack onto the "top" of the data structure
 * so that it will be retrived prior to the elements already in the stack.
 */
bool push(char* str) 
{
    s.strings[s.size++] = strdup(str);
    return false;
}

/**
 * Retrieves ("pops") the last ("top") element off of the stack, following
 * the "last-in, first-out" (LIFO) ordering of the data structure. Reduces
 * the size of the stack.
 */
char* pop(void)
{
    char *ptr = s.strings[--s.size]; 
    s.strings[s.size] = NULL;

    return ptr;   
}

/**
 * Implements some simple test code for our stack
 */
int main(void)
{
    // initialize the stack
    s.size = 0;

    printf("Pushing %d strings onto the stack...", CAPACITY);
    for (int i = 0; i < CAPACITY; i++)
    {
        char str[12];
        sprintf(str, "%d", i);
        push(strdup(str));
    }
    printf("done!\n");

    printf("Making sure that the stack size is indeed %d...", CAPACITY);
    assert(s.size == CAPACITY);
    printf("good!\n");

    printf("Making sure that push() now returns false...");
    assert(!push("too much!"));
    printf("good!\n");

    printf("Popping everything off of the stack...");
    char* str_array[CAPACITY];
    for (int i = 0; i < CAPACITY; i++)
    {
        str_array[i] = pop();
    }
    printf("done!\n");

    printf("Making sure that pop() returned values in LIFO order...");
    for (int i = 0; i < CAPACITY; i++)
    {
        char str[12];
        sprintf(str, "%d", CAPACITY - i - 1);
        assert(strcmp(str_array[i], str) == 0);
        free(str_array[i]);
    }
    printf("good!\n");

    printf("Making sure that the stack is now empty...");
    assert(s.size == 0);
    printf("good!\n");

    printf("Making sure that pop() now returns NULL...");
    assert(pop() == NULL);
    printf("good!\n");

    printf("\n********\nSuccess!\n********\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: And which one is line 52?

Comment: char *ptr = s.strings[--s.size];

Comment: You should use [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) to know answer of why segmentation fault.

Comment: `push("Too much!")`: this will write post the array range because your push function does not verify size. From there your program will have an erratic behaviour.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look at this piece:

```
printf("Making sure that push() now returns false...");
assert(!push("too much!"));
printf("good!\n");
```

Here you are pusing the string "too much" onto your stack, which is already full. Your push() function does not actually check that you exceeded the capacity, it just appends the string.

```
bool push(char* str) 
{
    s.strings[s.size++] = strdup(str);
    return false;
}
```

That means you're going over the bounds of your stack, trashing memory, setting the size of the stack to 11, and chaos ensues.

Maybe the push function should do:

```
bool push(char* str) 
{
   if (s.size >= CAPACITY)
      return false;

    s.strings[s.size++] = strdup(str);
    return true;
}
```

The pop function would need to do similar checks, otherwise you might end up with altering the size
of the stack even when it's empty:

```
char* pop(void)
{
    if (s.size == 0) 
        return NULL;

    char *ptr = s.strings[--s.size]; 
    s.strings[s.size] = NULL;

    return ptr;   
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In your `push` and `pop` functionw, you access `s.strings[--s.size]` / `s.strings[s.size++]` without checking if `s.size` is within reasonable bounds.

So, after pushing as much elements as possible on top of the stack, the line `assert(!push("too much!"));` adds one element beyond the allocated array.

Similarly, After popping every element inside your main function, the stack is empty and `assert(pop() == NULL);` tries to access the -1st element of the stack array, which is undefined behavior and another possible source of your segfault.

**Edit:** By the way, even thought this might be the source of the error you asked about, your code seems to be much more error-prone. Remember to always perform a bounds check when employing the use of pointer arithmetics or array access.